# Bug ao usar função array_diff_key()

Tags: php, array

Olá, eu preciso retornar a diferença entre dois arrays, então decidi utilizar a função nativa do PHP `array_diff_key()`, porém ela não me retorna nada.

```php
<?php

$array1 = array(
0   =>'DENTRO1',
1   =>'DENTRO2',
2   =>'DENTRO3',
4   =>'FORA1',
5   =>'DENTRO4'
);

$array2 = array(
0   =>'DENTRO1',
1   =>'DENTRO2',
2   =>'DENTRO3',
4   =>'FORA2',
5   =>'DENTRO4'
);

var_dump(array_diff_key($array1, $array2));
```

Alguém sabe uma maneira de realizar está operação, ou qual motivo/erro deste script do exemplo não me retornar nada?

Comment: Essa função retorna a diferença das arrays usando as **chaves** como meio de comparação. Se ambos forem compostos por **0, 1, 2, 3** nas chaves, não terá nenhuma diferença.

Comment: se eu quiser retornar a diferença dos elementos, qual devo utilizar?

Comment: `array_diff()` apenas.

Comment: obrigado, só mais uma dúvida, se eu tiver um array preenchido por um select, o array_diff() irá funcionar ? Exemplo: ($get_sql[] = odbc_result($result, "COLUMNNAME") e ($get_sql2[] = odbc_result($result, "COLUMNNAME2") e utilizar array_diff($get_sql, $get_sql2), é a forma correta?

Comment: Você precisará converter o objeto para um Json antes, senão o `array_diff` irá tentar comparar os elementos dentro da query por objetos em si. Tenta fazer um `array_diff(json_encode($array1), json_encode($array2));`.

Comment: Perfeito amigo, muito obrigado pela ajuda!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está comparando os dois arrays utilizando **as chaves** como o meio termo entre as duas arrays. No seu exemplo, as chaves são idênticas, portanto, não irá produzir o resultado que você espera.

A função que você precisa é a `array_diff()`, cuja compara **os valores das arrays**, e não suas chaves

```php
<?php

$array1 = array(
0   =>'DENTRO1',
1   =>'DENTRO2',
2   =>'DENTRO3',
4   =>'FORA1',
5   =>'DENTRO4'
);

$array2 = array(
0   =>'DENTRO1',
1   =>'DENTRO2',
2   =>'DENTRO3',
4   =>'FORA2',
5   =>'DENTRO4'
);

$diferenca = array_diff($array1, $array2);

var_dump($diferenca);
```

Resultado:

```
array(1) {
    [4] => string(5) "FORA1"
}
```

---

[Documentação do `array_diff_key()`.](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff-key.php)

[Documentação do `array_diff()`.](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff.php)